# How to equal the array into zero when no have value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have data here:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 147
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => D
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 147
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => D
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 145
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => R
    )
)
```

I'm done computing the reload, redemption and deposit and it's working, but If ever the siteID don't have a transaction of deposit [D] or reload [R ]or redemption [W] it should be equal to 0. my code is here:

```
   public function computeGHComponents()
    {
      error_reporting (E_ALL^ E_NOTICE);          

      foreach ($this->transaction as $t){

          $amount = (float) $t['Amount'];

            if (isset($this->totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ])){
                $this->totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] += (float) $amount;
            } else {
                 $this->totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] = (float) $amount;
            }
        }

     foreach($this->totals as $key => $value)


        {
          $this->result[$key] = array("Deposit"=>$value['D'], "Redemption"=>$value['W'], "Reload"=>$value['R']);

       }
     print_r($this->result); 

    }
```

The result should be shown like this:

```
 Array
 (
[147] => Array
    (
        [Deposit] => 1000
        [Redemption] => 0
        [Reload] => 0
    )

[145] => Array
    (
        [Deposit] => 0
        [Redemption] => 500.00
        [Reload] => 0
    )

 )
```

Thanks in advance and Please guide me in proper way.

Comment: Guys, Please help me, I know it's a little bit easier for you.Thank you so much.

Comment: What does the print_r display?

Comment: @ jmm, [Redemption] =>500.00 , [Deposit] => , [Reload] =>, there's no 0, if it dont have a value it should be equal to zero, how can I do that?

Comment: In the data definition the letters indicating the transaction type should be contained in quotes, since they are letters, not constant symbols.

Comment: @ arkascha, Im so sorry, I will keep it as a learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description is vague, there is information missing in the question. 
So this is kind of a blind shot, it might be what you ask but it might as well not:

In the assignment inside the last foreach, you can add 0 as a default value:

```
$this->result[$key] = array(
  "Deposit"    => array_key_exists('D',$value) ? $value['D'] : 0,            
  "Redemption" => array_key_exists('W',$value) ? $value['W'] : 0,           
  "Reload"     => array_key_exists('R',$value) ? $value['R'] : 0             
);
```

Comment: @ arkascha , if you dont mind, may I know what is the missing info about my question? and your codes doesn't work. Kindly review it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry for that, you are indeed correct. I corrected the code in the answer and verified it works as expected. But still I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: IN your question one has to assume that $value is the anonymous data structure you specify at the begin. But if that assumption is correct, then your example at the end does not make sense: it should work on keys _not_ populated in that data structur. Because: if $value _is_ that array then the values are defined.

Comment: Thank you for the modification of code, I got your point, sorry again and Thank you. I appreciate your codes.

Comment: @  arkascha, please forgive me, im so sorry.Now, I got your point. I will keep it as a learning.

Comment: @arkascha So you change your code to use ternary operater after my answer shows it?  They both do the same thing, think my is simpler.

Comment: @jimm Is this a big competition for you? May the fastest player win? I edited my answer because it contained errors since I gave the answer too fast if that is what you mean. Correcting ones answer when you problems are noticed is important for others consulting past answers. I didnt even read your answer. Why should I?

Comment: @jimm Ah, now I understand, you are frustrated your answer wasn't accepted. Sorry for that, but not my fault. Maybe the OP accepted mine because yours is much more confusing because it includes general advice instead of concentrating on the question posed. Try in future to answer only the question, not to explain your view of the world in total.

Comment: @arkascha, frustrated that my answer was accepted fours hour prior to you editing your code. I think the part of the reputation points are to make it a competition.  I think that is what keeps users coming back so frequently.  I certainly read every answer so I don't repeat and almost always learn something from every contribution.  I'm not mad, congrats on the question. Just trying to get use to the Stackoverflow eco-system.

Comment: @jmm Sure, all fine. Though certainly most people here com back because they want to give back for good advice they got here. There is no competition, sorry. The credits are to improve quality of posts and especially comments and stuff. And about your answer having been accepted before mine: sorry again, but as I said I did not look at that. It is not my fault, so dont rant at me.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on doing just one loop.

```
foreach ($this->transaction as $key => $t){

   $amount = $t['Amount'];

   // set up the array with each postion equal to zero
   $tranTypes = array("Deposit"= 0, "Redemption"=> 0 , "Reload"= 0);

   $transaction = $t['TransactionType'];

   switch($transaction){
     case "D":
        $tranTypes['Deposit'] = $amount;
     break;

     case "R":
         $tranTypes['Redemption'] = $amount;
     break;

     case "W":
         $tranTypes['Reload'] = $amount;
     break;

     }

    $this->result[$key] = $transaction;
}
```

OR THIS

```
 foreach($this->totals as $key => $value)


    {

     $this->result[$key]['Deposit']    = isset($value['D']) ? $value['D'] : 0;
     $this->result[$key]['Redemption'] = isset($value['W']) ? $value['W'] : 0; 
     $this->result[$key]['Reload']     = isset($value['R']) ? $value['R'] : 0;
    }
```

Comment: @ jmm , sorry but it doesn't meet what I need, my simple question is, if the Deposit , Reload and Redemption have no value, it should be equal to zero. Please review my question and I appreciate your codes.